# How to configure child routes properly?Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'parent/child1

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular2-routing, nested-routes

I am getting the following error after configuring child routes.

Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'parent/child1

app.routing.ts

```
{ path: 'home', component: homeComponent},
  { path: 'about', component: aboutComponent},
  { path: 'parent', component: parentComponent,
    children:[
    {
      path: '',
      redirectTo: '/parent/child1',
      pathMatch: 'full'
    },
    {
      path: 'child1',
      component: child1Component,
      outlet: 'subRouter'
    },
    {
      path: 'child2',
      component: child2Component,
      outlet: 'subRouter'
    }]
  },
{ path: '**', redirectTo: 'home', pathMatch: 'full' }
```

In my index.html, I have `<router-outlet></router-outlet>`

In my parent.htm(parentComponent) I have `<router-outlet name="subRouter"></router-outlet>`

What am i missing? Why i am getting that error? How can i resolve this error?

Answer (score 0):

The  `parent` route children `''` path redirection should changed to below, and explicitly mention `outlet:component` value.

```
redirectTo: '/child1(subRouter:child1)'
```

Because `/parent` will be implicitly included as you're redirecting from child route.

Comment: After making this change i am getting the same error with URL Segment: 'child1'

Comment: Nope. Still getting the same error. After specifying the outlet and component value